# Position Vector in Vertexshader conflicts with glTranslate

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

I'm trying to render an image and offset it by using glTranslate:

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(x, y, 0.0f);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
glPopMatrix();
```

I'm also using a shader, and in the vertexshader I set the position of the vertices:

```
in vec2 position;
in vec3 color;
out vec3 Color;
void main() {
   Color = color;
   gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

However, this always renders the square at the same position. I'm thinking this is because the position vector is always the same. How can I use this shader but still be able to move the image around with glTranslate? I suspect I have to change my shader input, but how?

Comment: FYI, `glTranslatef (...)` multiplies a matrix on the CPU-side of things but does not actually do any vertex transformation. Judging by your code the matrix you are manipulating is probably `GL_MODELVIEW`. That matrix can be accessed from some shader versions (version 1.10-1.30 and 1.40+ compatibility) using `gl_ModelViewMatrix`. The fixed-function vertex transform (what happens when you don't use shaders) is basically `gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * vec4 (position, 0.0, 1.0)` (or `ftransform` as ratchet freak explains).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

glTranslatef changes the MVP matrix which gets passed as a uniform into the vertex shader. There is a shortcut in pre 150 by using

```
gl_Position = ftransform();
```

Which applies the transformation matrices to the input position as it was passed in with `glVertex*`.

However glsl 150 core doesn't allow using that uniform or that function. Instead create a matrix uniform and pass it in:

```
#version 150 core
in vec2 position;
in vec3 color;
out vec3 Color;

uniform mat4 mvp;

void main() {
   Color = color;
   gl_Position = mvp * vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: The version doesn't really matter, I edited my post and deleted the version. What method should I then use? ftransform();?

Comment: @user3162904 if you want to be current with regards to the openGL practices then managing your own matrix with the second method is better.